# flutter_facebook_login CocoaPods dependency error

Tags: facebook, dart, flutter, facebook-login, flutter-plugin

I am try add facebook login to Flutter app. I am use `flutter_facebook_login`. But when I try build for iOS give error:

```
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit":
      In Podfile:
        flutter_facebook_login (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
          FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.39.1)

    None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.39.1)`.

    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * mistyped the name or version.
     * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.




Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone X.
```

I no install pod manually because `flutter_facebook_login` readme say:

> (Note: you can skip "Step 2: Set up Your Development Environment").

Anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

According to this *diegoveloper's answer* flutter_facebook_login github issue.

https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/issues/201

- `flutter clean`
- Remove `ios/Podfile.lock` file
- Go to the `Podfile` file and changed from `platform :ios, '9.0'` to `platform :ios, '11.0'`
  (In my case, some libs don't support 11.0 and I use
  platform :ios, '9.0
  then set deployment target in runner.xcsworkspace to 9.0 and it work.)
- Go to the terminal , `ios` directory and run `pod install`
- Run the project again.

Comment: Make sure "platform :ios, '11.0'" line is not commented out.

Answer (score 4):

just update your podfile .

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

try to pod install again in terminal.
pod install

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem some time ago and I was able to solve this with a manual approach.
Make sure that you have in your `pubspec.yaml` `flutter_facebook_login: ˆ2.0.0` declared and getted.

In your project `root directory` navigate to `ios` > `.symlinks` > `plugins` > `flutter_facebook_login` > `ios` > `flutter_facebook_login.podspec`

You will change some fields inside `flutter_facebook_login.podspec`.

```
s.version          = '2.0.0'
```

and

```
s.dependency 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.29'
```

after this in your osx box inside of `ios` directory of your project run `pod deintegrate` and `pod update` return to root project directory run `flutter clean`
and try to build your project again.

Here is an example of my `flutter_facebook_login.podspec` that works fine into one of my projects. I hope it helps.

```
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'flutter_facebook_login'
  s.version          = '2.0.0'
  s.summary          = 'A Flutter plugin for allowing users to authenticate with native Android &amp; iOS Facebook login SDKs.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A Flutter plugin for allowing users to authenticate with native Android &amp; iOS Facebook login SDKs.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.dependency 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.29'

  # https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14161
  #s.static_framework = true

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have not try this yet. Is safe to modify this? If `flutter_facebook_login` get new update, will also update this? Or is lock?

Comment: Well I make this change in a project some time ago and until currents days is all good. About updates it's hard too say because before you make this changes the plugin version is already locked right...? You can make some tests about it but I can grant that with this changes you will get a build successfully.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am ask because I want make sure dependency is update when it get new version (for example when author release version 2.1.0)

Answer (score 2):

1. open terminal and go to root package directory using `cd the_root_package_path`
2. type `flutter clean`
3. open `podfile` and uncomment :  `# platform :ios, '11.0'`
4. run `pod install`

had the same problem, tried everything, this worked for me.