# podfile error when running flutter application

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-plugin, podfile, flutter-ios

This is the error when I try to run ios app.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit":
      In Podfile:
        flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`) was resolved to 0.3.1, which depends on
          FBSDKLoginKit (~> 7.1.0)

 

        flutter_facebook_login (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
          FBSDKLoginKit (~> 5.5)
```

and I have done some research and show some article saying to do flutter clean and deleting podfile and then rerunning.  But that didn't save me. Anyone know to bypass this.

Comment: please visit to this answer this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596988/flutter-facebook-login-cocoapods-dependency-error

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I already did that but when I run pod install the error always pops up

Comment: okay please try once by setting platform :ios, '9.0'

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede yes I had tried that one too. still on the loop

Comment: did someone find out the solution ?

Comment: yeah i came up with some solutions

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @AimnBlbol can post your pubcyaml file

Comment: Can you please post your solution to this?

Comment: so... any solutions?